# Kafka - Know if Consumer is up to date

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using Kafka 0.9.0 with the native Java consumer client. 
If I have 1 Topic with 1 Partition
Can someone tell me if I do:
seekToEnd(MyTopic);
poll(x);

I will only get the last record, hence I will know that I am in the last position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will only get the last (newest) record, because the [`seekToEnd()`](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seekToEnd(org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition...)) method "*evaluates lazily*" so the end is not calculated until `poll()` is called. Of course, by the time the `poll()` method returns, more messages could have been added; so there is no guarantee your offset is "in the last position" except at the instant that the method executes.

Comment: Thanks for the Answear jaco